# Is it possible to use List<Object> instead of csv files in spring batch as input

Tags: spring-batch

for a period of time i'm looking for a solution to resolve a problem with spring batch. I should use spring batch to reproduce/ create new csv files from csv files.
Here an example:

```
outPut   | inPut
------   | ------
File1    | source1
File2    | source2 and source 3
File3    | source1 and source2
File4    | Csource3
```

Here is an example to create the Output number one for example File1:

```
 @Bean
        public Step step1() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("createFile1")
                    .<source1, File1> chunk(10)
                    .reader(source1Reader())
                    .processor(transformesource1ToFile1())
                    .writer(File1Writer())
                    .build();
        }
```

And this it will be the same for the other outPut Files, but as you can see some output use the same source,  in this fact i can't read the same data twice to repoduce a new output, so I tried to store them as resource on a map ( resource will be used more than ones) ie, i will have

`List<source1>, List<source2>, List<source3>` to access these sources again without passing by reader every time.

Now my question is haw can i access/get these list in spring Batch in ItemProcessor / ItemWriter / itemReader ?

can i inject /pass these List to an itemProcessor as it was the returned result of an itemReader

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction, is there a may to create a custom reader ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on this post [Spring Batch Tutorial: Creating a Custom ItemReader](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-creating-a-custom-itemreader/)

It was a custom reader that reads the input data from a List.